# How to checkout .git

Tags: git

My boss gave me a path: xxx@yyy:git/zzzz.git
I tried git checkout xxx@yyy:git/zzzz.git, but got "fatal: Not a git repository Failed to find a valid git directory."
I also tried xxx@yyy:/git/zzzz.git and xxx@yyy://git/zzzz.git, all returned the same information
I also tried git branch, but got "fatal: Not a git repository"
What should I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://gitimmersion.com/ is a good GIT overview, you should go through that before you start using git. As mentioned already you should do

Clone repro

```
$ git clone xxx@yyy:git/zzzz.git
```

Assign the original repo to a remote called "upstream"

```
$ cd zzzz
$ git remote add upstream xxx@yyy:git/zzzz.git
$ git fetch upstream
```

Comment: After clone the sequence with git remote add and and git fetch is not necessary. The cloned repository will be linked to the original one and remote name will be "origin"

Comment: thanks, my practice / common practice - might not be best practice, think I got that behaviour from github

Comment: the `git remote add upstream` part is only useful when you're cloning your own repository that you forked from another 'upstream' repository. GitHub only tell you to do that in those circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
git clone xxx@yyy:git/zzzz.git zzzzz
```

Also make sure to read the git documentation before you start messing around with the code.

Answer (score 3):

Try "git clone" instead of "git checkout"